# How do you rescue I18n::MissingTranslationData?

Tags: ruby, internationalization

I want to be able to rescue `I18n::MissingTranslationData` like so:

```
begin
  value = I18n.t('some.key.that.does.not.exist')
  puts value
  return value if value
rescue I18n::MissingTranslationData
  puts "Kaboom!"
end
```

I tried the above, but it doesn't seem to go into the rescue block. I just see, on my console (because of `puts`): `translation missing: some.key.that.does.not.exist`. I never see `Kaboom!`.

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO, it's pretty strange but in the current version of `i18n (0.5.0)` you should pass an exception that you want to rescue:

```
require 'i18n'
begin
  value = I18n.translate('some.key.that.does.not.exist', :raise => I18n::MissingTranslationData)
  puts value
  return value if value
rescue I18n::MissingTranslationData
  puts "Kaboom!"
end
```

and it will be fixed in the future 0.6 release (you can test it - https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n)

Comment: Has this been fixed? I checked out the github and it doesn't look like it is fixed.

Answer (score 5):

Same as above but **nicer**.

```
v = "doesnt_exist"
begin
  puts I18n.t "langs.#{v}", raise: true
rescue
  puts "Nooo #{v} has no Translation!"
end
```

or

```
puts I18n.t("langs.#{v}", default: "No Translation!")
```

or

```
a = I18n.t "langs.#{v}", raise: true rescue false
unless a
  puts "Update your YAML!"
end
```

Comment: I18n.t("langs.#{v}", default: "No Translation!") # works

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of I18n, the exception you're looking for is actually called `MissingTranslation`.  The default exception handler for I18n rescues it silently, and just passes it up to ArgumentError to print an error message and not much else.  If you actually want the error thrown, you'll need to override the handler.

See [the source code for i18n exceptions](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb), and section 6.2 of [RailsGuides guide to I18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) for how to write a custom handler

Comment: Instead of saying current version, please be specific.  Same thing with you source code link: please link to a specific revision instead of master.

Answer (score 0):

Note that now you simply pass in `:raise => true`

```
assert_raise(I18n::MissingTranslationData) { I18n.t(:missing, :raise => true) }
```

...which will raise `I18n::MissingTranslationData`.

See https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/tests/lookup.rb

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job. When using `rescue` I would always catch specific errors. using rescue without a specific error can lead to unexpected behaviour.

```
require 'i18n'
begin
  value = I18n.t 'some.key.that.does.not.exist', raise: true
  puts value
rescue I18n::MissingTranslationData
  puts "Kaboom!"
end
```