# Disable translation_missing for english only in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, internationalization, translation

Is there a way to prevent `.translation_missing` class from appearing in views if the language is english? Since the english text is correct I don't need to translate it.

Right now I added styles to mask `span.translation_missing` if the locale is default span, but I'd rather want it to not appear at all if the locale is `:en`

**Update:** Just to be clear, I do translations in `.erb` files, so say `<%= t "Menu item" %>` becomes `<span class="translation_missing">Menu item<span>` which is overkill. I just need it to leave the original string alone for `:en` locale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this through the standard methods, but you could just add a patch like this:

```
module I18n::MissingTranslation::Base

  def html_message_with_en_fix
    (locale == :en) ? key : html_message_without_en_fix
  end
  alias_method_chain :html_message, :en_fix

  def message_with_en_fix
    (locale == :en) ? key : message_without_en_fix
  end
  alias_method_chain :message, :en_fix

end
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use a patch, you can also define your own method and catch the exception yourself:

```
def my_translate(key)
  begin
    I18n.t(key, :raise => I18n::MissingTranslationData)
  rescue I18n::MissingTranslationData
    (I18n.locale == :en) ? key.to_s : I18n.t(key)
  end
end
```

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027471/how-do-you-rescue-i18nmissingtranslationdata).

(I've updated both answers to return the translation string rather thank blank/nil.)

Comment: Unfortunately produces `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass)` error in production. I was hoping there is a way to do it without patching.

Comment: Updated my answer so it returns an empty string rather than `nil`. I agree that patching is not the most elegant approach, but it should work.

Comment: Added an alternative approach which doesn't require a patch. See also this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027471/how-do-you-rescue-i18nmissingtranslationdata

Comment: Update(1) retuns empty string if translation is missing indeed, but this way all the text in the english version is gone.

Comment: So you just want to show the key if you're in the English locale? That wasn't very clear. Anyway I updated my answer to do that.

Comment: No worries! Now that I understand what you wanted it makes more sense.